# how can I serialize 2 sets using nlohmann/json.hpp

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have two unordered sets of pairs (X,Y) implemented using boost hash and I would like to convert them to a Json file that has a special format.

```
unordered_set<pair<int,int>> visited, cleaned
```

. I want them to be represented this way in Json format using nlohmann/json.hpp C++:

```
{
  "visited": [
    {
      "X": 2,
      "Y": 2
    },
    {
      "X": 3,
      "Y": 0
    },
    {
      "X": 3,
      "Y": 1
    },
    {
      "X": 3,
      "Y": 2
    }
  ],
  "cleaned": [
    {
      "X": 2,
      "Y": 2
    },
    {
      "X": 3,
      "Y": 0
    },
    {
      "X": 3,
      "Y": 2
    }
  ],
}
```

can anyone help me with the c++ code for this part? 
my code is

```
for (auto it = visited.begin(); it != visited.end(); ++it)
    {
        j2["visited"]["X"]=it->second;
        j2["visited"]["Y"] = it->first;
    }   
    for (auto it = cleaned.begin(); it != cleaned.end(); ++it)
    {
        j2["cleaned"]["X"] = it->second;
        j2["cleaned"]["Y"] = it->first;
    }
```

and it produces:

```
{
    "cleaned": {
        "X": 3,
        "Y": 2
    },
    "visited": {
        "X": 3,
        "Y": 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON format you want contains arrays. Use something like this to explicitly create
them:

```
nlohmann::json arr;
for (auto it = visited.begin(); it != visited.end(); ++it) {
    nlohmann::json o;
    o["X"] = it->second;
    o["Y"] = it->first;
    arr.push_back(o);
}

j2["visited"] = arr;
```

And similarly for the second part.

Comment: I have done like this: 
`my_json j2;
 j2["visited"] = {};
 for (auto it = visited.begin(); it != visited.end(); ++it)
 {
  j2["visited"] += { {"X", it->second}, { "Y",it->first } };

 }
`

and it worked as well. 
Thank you very much